# Nuget package wrongly pulls in net standard libs instead of full

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, .net-standard

I have a nuget package that multi targets netstandard1.4 and net461.

When I use this nuget package from a .net 4.6.1 project pulls in all the system.* assemblies and the NETStandard.Library

Why is it doing this and how do I get it to reference the net461 version, without all the net standard stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it..

My Nuget package had a dependency on another package. I had a reference to the net standard version of that other package.

Updating to a multi targeted version of the other package fixed my problem.

Comment: how do you choose the version of the package to the one that isn't built against .NET Standard? I don't see that option, I can only select version number but not platform.